# How to get userid from a string in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to ban users. Theirs username+discriminator are write in a .txt file line per line.

Exemple:

```
user#0123
user2#0123
user3#0123
```

But the function ban() work with the ID of the user.

So, I need to know how to "transphorm" the username+discriminator to user.id

My code start with that:

```py
    file = r'C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\Autrebot\files\blacklist.txt'
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    @commands.command()
    async def banlist(self, ctx):
        with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as file_in:       

            for line in file_in:
                await ctx.guild.ban(line, reason='blacklist')
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use discord.py MemberConverter to convert the string user into the user object. [Docs of memberconverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter.convert)

It will give you the member object and the properties of it is here mentioned in [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)

Resulting code can be something like -

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.command()
async def banlist(self, ctx):
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as file_in:       
    for line in file_in:
        try:
            member = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, line)
            await ctx.guild.ban(member.id, reason='blacklist')
        except commands.errors.MemberNotFound:
            #  member not found here, handle it
```

Answer (score 1):

To "transphorm" the username + discriminator to user.id you must use `class discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter` (not to be confused with UserConverter). The other user answered very well (@Priyam)

Comment: But can I ban users who are not on my server?